# Gatsby markdown - is it posible to save somehow svg in markdown

Tags: svg, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am very new to Gatsby...
I would like to generate 4 components on front page from markdown content - 4 blocks, each image (svg), title, text.
Is it possible at all?
There is no problem to display svg image when I import it as:

```
import Svg from "../assets/svg/image.svg"
```

But when I try to build a query it does not work:

```
query {
        file(relativePath: { eq: "svg/marketing.svg" }) {
              childImageSharp {
                  fluid {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                  }
              }
        }
    }
```

This query returns no result, but is ok if it is for png file...
I tried to pass the path to svg in frontmatter data and use it to display image but it does not work..

Any ideas?

EDIT: I understand now that that you need to use `publicURL` not `path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find solution myself...

**The key was to get the publicURL of svg image and render it with `<img>` tag**

Each markdown document:

```
---
title: "Title content"
text: "Text content"
svg_name: "svg1"
---
```

Place svg1.svg image in assets folder.

I had to query for frontmatter from markdown and for svg files:

```
query Services {
            allFile(filter: {extension: {eq: "svg"}}) {
                nodes {
                    publicURL
                    name
                }
            }
            allMarkdownRemark(sort: {fields: frontmatter___order}) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        text
                        title
                        svg_name
                        order
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

then construct an object:

```
const {allMarkdownRemark, allFile} = data
const documents = allMarkdownRemark.nodes
const pictures = allFile.nodes

let services = documents.map(doc => {
        let pic = pictures.find(p => p.name === doc.frontmatter.svg_name)
        return doc = {...doc.frontmatter, ...pic}

    })
```

Then map over the `services` and display svg with img tag:

```
<h2>{title}</h2>
<p>{text}</p>
<img src={publicURL} alt="Alt text" />
```

Maybe not most elegant solution, but works.